# How do I find the qubit trajectory on the Bloch sphere when implementing an RY rotation on an IBM backend?

Tags: programming, qiskit, openpulse

Suppose I use Qiskit to prepare the $| + \rangle$ state using a RY rotation,

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.ry(np.pi / 2, 0)
```

I would like to know the Bloch sphere trajectory of the qubit *on the physical level* when I do this. Naively, I would expect that this is implemented as a rotation $\pi / 2$ rotation about the $Y$ axis which is the minimal distance path. But as I know, this circuit can be introspected in various ways.

For example, when I `transpile` the ciruit to the `ibmq_armonk` backend, I get the following circuit level description
[image]

which suggests that actually the qubit goes from $| 0 \rangle$ to the xy-plane at some angle $\pi / 4$ *away* from $+x$ and is then corrected with the final $RZ(\pi / 2)$.

I can then introspect even further at the pulse-level using the `build_schedule` utility obtained via `from qiskit import schedule as build_schedule` to obtain the description of the circuit as

```
Schedule((0, ShiftPhase(-1.5707963267948966, DriveChannel(0))), (0, Play(Drag(duration=320, amp=(0.3705139948561776-0.07637772314715083j), sigma=80, beta=-1.0562934233232557), DriveChannel(0))), (320, ShiftPhase(-4.71238898038469, DriveChannel(0))), name="circuit32")
```

Is there a way--from the pulse level description--to infer the time-dynamics of the state *as I apply the RY* rotation? It seems like I could possibly apply the DRAG pulse with half the amplitude, but

1. I'm not sure how to simulate pulse schedules to get the output state
2. I'm not sure that is sound since the DRAG pulse has a complicated definition.

In regards to (1), I tried the following code

```
backend_sim = qiskit.providers.aer.PulseSimulator()
backend_sim.set_options(system_model=backend.backend)
pulse_qobj = assemble(sched.sched, backend=backend_sim)
results = backend_sim.run(pulse_qobj)
```

by attempting to guess what `system_model` meant in this [guide](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.PulseSimulator.html), but this didn't work. Note that `backend.backend` is just the armonk `backend` wrapped into a custom class and `sched.sched` is just a `Schedule` object with the DRAG pulse and measurement also wrapped into a custom class.